# Analyze the killed java process in hadoop cluster

Tags: java, mapreduce, mapr

Java program is executing in Hadoop cluster. It got OutOfMemoryError during the execution and process stopped. I want to analyze the killed java process for memory & other details.
Where i can find the killed process log files?
I used sar utility to analysis the memory but it shows only system memory instead of process memory.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `-XX:ErrorFile=<your location>/hs_err_pid<pid>.log` as JVM parameter to set the `hs_error` file location.

Comment: Thanks gyan. I will add it now. What is the default location of the error log in case of the completed java process.

Comment: By default it resides in `tmp` location like `/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/local/userlogs/job_201802111641_0059/attempt_201802111641_0059_r_000001_1/stdout`. But the problem is that `tmp` locations are often cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

First, perhaps you JVM has not been configured with enough heap size for your application.

That said, I have a little recommendation based on my experience. I think you should enable these flags to investigate which objects are consuming too much space.

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=path
```

The first flag is going to dump the heap in case of OOM exception and the second one is going to set the path where the JVM saves that dump file.

After getting the heap dump file you should use Memory Analyzer Tool (https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to see possible memory leaks caused by applications.

In addition, it is important to measure the GC process and you can do this with these flags.

```
-XX:+PrintReferenceGC 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps - 
XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy 
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M -
Xloggc:/some/where/gc.log
```

The GC.log can be analyzed using this online tool

http://gceasy.io/